# Am I using the word “firebrand” correctly?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I’m developing a 3-pronged description of my professional self for LinkedIn using words that start with f (example: “freelancer”).... At the moment, one of my prongs is “firebrand of innovative content strategy”.

My question is— Can you be a firebrand OF something? Does that usage of “of” make sense here? Or should it be “about”? Or just “Content Strategy Firebrand.”

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry to point out that here, what you're asking is by no means the worst of your problems. 

May we ignore the pre-amble and work with ‘… one of my prongs is “firebrand of innovative content strategy” ‘?

Either way no, you can’t be a firebrand *of* anything.

No, your usage of “of” doesn’t make sense.

No, it shouldn’t be “about”

No, it shouldn’t be ‘just “Content Strategy Firebrand”.’

Answer (score 1):

Only one definition I've seen has a meaning of being passionate without mentioning creating trouble, that is the one from Oxford Living Dictionaries. The others are as follow:

> 1.A person who stirs up trouble or kindles a revolt.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/firebrand)
>
> 2.a person who causes unrest or is very energetic
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/firebrand)
>
> 2.a person who kindles strife or encourages unrest. 
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/firebrand)
>
> 2 : one that creates unrest or strife (as in aggressively promoting a
>   cause) : agitator 
>  [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firebrand)
>
> a person who causes political or social trouble by opposing authority
>   and encouraging others to do so 
>  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/firebrand)
>
> someone who has strong feelings, especially about politics, and wants to change things or encourage other people to feel the same.
>   a.someone who has strong feelings of anger or enthusiasm and often expresses them
>   [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/firebrand)
>
> someone who tries to make people angry about a law, government etc so
>   that they will try to change it
>  [Longman Dictionary of
>   Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/firebrand)
>
> 1.An argumentative troublemaker or revolutionary; one who agitates against the current situation.
>  [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firebrand)

It sounds to me the word has connotations of intractability or being a trouble-maker. You may want to think about that when using the word. There's nothing wrong using "of" after a noun to mean being part of or related to. "Firebrand of the movement", "Aficionado of film", "enthusiast of vintage cars".

Answer (score 0):

A cursory Google search returned 56 700 results, the majority referring to [The Firebrand of Florence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Firebrand_of_Florence),

> a Broadway operetta in two acts, written by Kurt Weill (music), Ira Gershwin (lyrics), and Edwin Justus Mayer and Gershwin, based on Mayer's play.

American Heritage Magazine refers to Samuel Adams as [Firebrand of the Revolution](https://www.americanheritage.com/content/firebrand-revolution)

[Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/firebrand), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/firebrand), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/firebrand), and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firebrand) dictionaries all have similar definitions for a firebrand,

> A person who is very passionate about a particular cause

but don't use "about" or "of" with the word in any of their example sentences.

Even though usage of the word doesn't seem very common in the context you have given,
both

> a firebrand of innovative content strategy

and

> an innovative content stategy firebrand

should do.

Answer (score -1):

**firebrand**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70522?rskey=z3DmdG&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> 3. A person who, or (occasionally) a thing which, kindles strife, inflames passions, etc., esp. in a political context; an agitator.
>      Later also more generally: a person who is full of passion or energy.

As in:

> I am a firebrand of innovative content strategy.

or

> I am known as an "innovative content strategy" firebrand.